# Can exists an endomorphism $f:\Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$, $f(z)=\Re(z)+\Im(z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I believe that it is not possible as you can't make a matrix of this application where $(a+bi)\rightarrow (a+b)$. Are my thoughts correct?

Moreover, I believe that an endomorphism $\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ of this application would be possible, because the matrix would be $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1& 1\\ 0& 0 \end{array}\right)$. But it is not possible to it with an endormophism over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hint: Is $f$ linear with respect to multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No, it's not possible. So it would not be a linear application, hence it is not an endomorphism. Thanks!\

Comment: If you consider $\Bbb C$ to be a real vector space over $\Bbb R$ of dimension $2$, then it is valid to refer to the map $a + bi \mapsto a + b$ as an endomoprhism

Comment: The word endomorphism has many different meanings depending on context, you really need to clarify: group endomorphism, ring endomorphism, $F$-vector space endomorphism., $F$-algebra endomorphism..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you want it to be an endomorphism over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. As you observed it is indeed an endomorphism over $\mathbb R$ (i.e. if you consider $\mathbb C$ as a 2-dimensional real vector space), and can be represented by the matrix you gave. However it is not an endomorphism over $\mathbb C$ because for example $$f(iz) = \Re(iz)+\Im(iz) = -\Im(z)+\Re(z)$$
but this is not the same as
$$i f(z) = i(\Re(z)+\Im(z)). $$
Another way to see this immediately is to note that the image of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, which is not a complex vector space. But the image of a linear transformation of vector spaces is always a vector space over the base field.